# PIC24FJ64GB110 and 25AA160

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, microchip

I have a 25AA160 wired to a PIC24FJ64GB110 (100-pin):

SO -  RD3 (pin78)
SI -  RD2 (pin77)
SCK - RD1 (pin76)

SS is not used. CS\ is wired to GND and WP\, HOLD\ are wired to VDD.

I copy/paste code from Microchip and modified few lines to accomplish my hardware configuration.

This is the code (sorry a bit of long):

```
#define EEPROM_PAGE_SIZE    (unsigned)64
#define EEPROM_PAGE_MASK    (unsigned)0x003f
#define EEPROM_CMD_READ     (unsigned)0b00000011
#define EEPROM_CMD_WRITE    (unsigned)0b00000010
#define EEPROM_CMD_WRDI     (unsigned)0b00000100
#define EEPROM_CMD_WREN     (unsigned)0b00000110
#define EEPROM_CMD_RDSR     (unsigned)0b00000101
#define EEPROM_CMD_WRSR     (unsigned)0b00000001

#define EEPROM_SCK_TRIS     TRISDbits.TRISD1
#define EEPROM_SDO_TRIS     TRISDbits.TRISD3
#define EEPROM_SDI_TRIS     TRISDbits.TRISD2

struct  STATREG{
    unsigned    WIP:1;
    unsigned    WEL:1;
    unsigned    BP0:1;
    unsigned    BP1:1;
    unsigned    RESERVED:3;
    unsigned    WPEN:1;
};

union _EEPROMStatus_{
    struct  STATREG Bits;
    unsigned char   Char;
};

#define Hi(X)   (unsigned char)((X>>8)&0x00ff)
#define Lo(X)   (unsigned char)(X&0x00ff)

void SPI2INTInit()  
{  
    IFS2bits.SPI2IF = 0;    // clear interrupt flag  
    IEC2bits.SPI2IE = 0;    // enable interrupt  
    SPI2CON1 = SPI_MASTER;  // select mode    SPI_MASTER = 0x0120  
    SPI2STAT = SPI_ENABLE;  // enable the peripheral  SPI_ENABLE = 0x8000  
} 

void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _SPI2Interrupt()  
{  
   IFS2bits.SPI2IF = 0;  
}

void EEPROMWriteEnable()  
{
    unsigned char Local_8;  
    Local_8 = writeSPI2(EEPROM_CMD_WREN);  
}

void EEPROMWriteDisable()  
{
    unsigned char Local_8;  
    Local_8 = writeSPI2(EEPROM_CMD_WRDI);  
}


void EEPROMWriteByte(unsigned char Data, unsigned int Address)  
{  
    unsigned char Local_8;  

    Local_8 = writeSPI2(EEPROM_CMD_WRITE);  

    Local_8 = writeSPI2(Hi(Address));  
    Local_8 = writeSPI2(Lo(Address));  

    Local_8 = writeSPI2(Data);  


    // wait for completion of previous write operation  
    while(EEPROMReadStatus().Bits.WIP);  

}

unsigned char EEPROMReadByte(unsigned int Address)
{
    unsigned char Local_8;


    Local_8 = writeSPI2(EEPROM_CMD_READ);

    Local_8 = writeSPI2(Hi(Address));
    Local_8 = writeSPI2(Lo(Address));

    Local_8 = writeSPI2(0);

    return Local_8;
}

union _EEPROMStatus_ EEPROMReadStatus()
{
    unsigned char Local_8;

    Local_8 = writeSPI2(EEPROM_CMD_RDSR);
    Local_8 = writeSPI2(0);

    return (union _EEPROMStatus_)Local_8;
}


void main()
{
WORD rxData;
    WORD txData = 0x5AAC;

SPI2INTInit();

    // Write MS byte into EEPROM address. 
    EEPROMWriteByte(Hi(txData), 0x10);
    // Write LS byte into EEPROM address. 
    EEPROMWriteByte(Lo(txData), 0x11);

   // Now Readback one data from the serial eeprom.

    // Read MS byte from EEPROM address.
    rxData =  EEPROMReadByte(0x10);
    rxData = (rxData<<8) & 0xff00;
    // Read LS byte from EEPROM address.
    rxData |= (EEPROMReadByte(0x11) & 0x00ff);
    // verify write and read SPI EEPROM (single byte)

    if( rxData != txData )
    DebugMsg("EEPROM error");
}
```

I always got "EEPROM error" and I could not see any pulses on SO, SI and SCK on oscilloscope.

I think somewhere in my code I have to tell SPI2 to use these three I/O lines as SO, SI and SCK:

```
#define EEPROM_SCK_TRIS     TRISDbits.TRISD1
#define EEPROM_SDO_TRIS     TRISDbits.TRISD3
#define EEPROM_SDI_TRIS     TRISDbits.TRISD2
```

but, how? Am I right?

Many thanks

Wei

Comment: Hi   
Do I have to use pull-up resistors on SO, SI and SCK lines? I do not think I do. I tried both (with and without), no effect.  

Wei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PIC24FJ microcontrollers use Peripheral Pin Select registers to map peripherals like the UART and SPI ports to specific pins.

Pins available that can be used for remapping are marked as RPxx or RPIxx (input only) on the Pin Diagram (100-pin TQFP) for the PIC24FJGB110.

The mapping of pins in your case would be:

RD1 (SCK) is also RP24, RD2 (SDI) is also RP23, and RD3 (SDO) is also RP22.

The associated code to set this up:

```
#include <PPS.h>    // bring in header for pin remapping peripheral library functions

#define EEPROM_SDI_PIN     23
#define EEPROM_SDO_PIN     OUT_PIN_PPS_RP22
#define EEPROM_SCK_PIN     OUT_PIN_PPS_RP24

IN_FN_PPS_SDI2 = EEPROM_SDI_PIN;           // map SDI2 to RP23 
EEPROM_SDO_PIN = OUT_FN_PPS_SDO2;          // map SDO2 to RP22 
EEPROM_SCK_PIN = OUT_FN_PPS_SCK2OUT;       // map SCK2 to RP24
```

Note in the case of inputs, pins are assigned to a function; whereas for outputs, functions are assigned to a pin.  See the Peripheral Pin Select section in the PIC24FJGB110 datasheet for more info.

You should also set the TRIS pins for the output pins to 0:

```
EEPROM_SCK_TRIS = 0;
EEPROM_SDO_TRIS = 0;
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your help!!!  


I read this: TABLE 4-27: PERIPHERAL PIN SELECT REGISTER MAP. I am so close, but just the last bit:
'
 EEPROM_SCK_TRIS = 0;
 EEPROM_SDO_TRIS = 0;

 // input: assign a RPxx number to a function
 RPINR22bits.SDI2R = 23;
 
 // output: assign a function to a RPxx pin
 RPOR11bits.RP22R = x;
 RPOR12bits.RP24R = y;
'
what value should I put to x and y to present SPI2 - SO and SPI2 - SCK?


cheers 

wei

Comment: @Wei, OUT_FN_PPS_SDO2 is defined as 10, and OUT_FN_PPS_SCK2OUT is defined as 11 in the file PPS.h -- I forgot to add that as an include statement.  I have edited my answer.  On my system, PPS.h is located at  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\mplabc30\v3.30b\support\peripheral_24F\PPS.h  You may need to add the appropriate path to your include directories.

Comment: Thanks for that!

I now have pulses on SCK and MOSI, but nothing on MISO. Do I have to use a pull-up resistor? I tried a 10K on MISO, the processor stuck when writing a command.

cheers

Comment: Make sure the lines are connected correctly.  The SO pin of the EEPROM should be connected to the SDI pin of the PIC24, and the SI pin of the EEPROM should be connected to SDO of the PIC24.  Also, WPbar and HOLDbar of the EEPROM should be tied to VCC unless you are driving them from the PIC.  The datasheet for the EEPROM doesn't mention anything about a pullup needed on SO.

Comment: Hi

Many thanks! It turned out a faulty EEPROM chip. I replaced a new one it works like charm.

Thanks again for all your help. My next challenge reading A/D data from MCP3425 through I2C. I hope it wouldn't be too hard.

BTW: Do how I spell your name correctly, just call you 'tcrosley' okay? I am trying to be polite.


cheers

Wei

Comment: @Wei, my user name is made up of the first initial of my first name and then my last name.  Some others do it the other way, first name and first initial of last name.  Then others just use their first name, others their full name, or maybe something complete unrelated.  In my case you can see my real name in my profile.